# Using GROUP BY to group orders by orderid

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to know the best way to group each result by `orderid` using the `GROUP BY` statement.

The current query:

```
SELECT T.orderid,
       Inventory.partid,
       Inventory.Description,
       OrderItems.Qty,
       '$' + STR(Inventory.price,8,2) AS UnitPrice,
       '$' + STR(OriginalCost,8,2) AS OriginalCost,
       '$' + STR(QuantityDiscount,8,2) AS QuantityDiscount, 
       '$' + STR((OriginalCost  - QuantityDiscount),8,2) AS FinalCost
  FROM (
       SELECT Orders.Orderid, Inventory.partid, Description, Qty, 
              Inventory.price AS UnitPrice, 
              (OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) AS OriginalCost, 
              CASE WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 5
                     THEN ((OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) * .05)
                   WHEN OrderItems.Qty >= 10
                     THEN ((OrderItems.Qty * Inventory.price) * .10)
                   ELSE 0
              END AS QuantityDiscount
         FROM Orders,OrderItems,Inventory
       ) AS T
  JOIN OrderItems ON OrderItems.orderid = OrderItems.orderid
  JOIN Inventory ON ORDERITEMS.partid = Inventory.partid
ORDER BY T.QTY DESC
```

The DB diagram:

[image]

**Sample Result**
This is part of the result I get from the current code. I want all the Orders with the same id should be grouped together.

```
orderid partid Description Qty  UnitPrice OriginalCost QuantityDiscount FinalCost
------- ------ ----------- ---- --------- ------------ ---------------- ---------
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
6148    1006   gizmo       1    $   11.35 $  113.50    $    5.67        $  107.83
```

Comment: So you want 9 rows that are absolutely identical?

Comment: What did you try so far? If you just group by `T.orderid`, you cannot use any of those `Inventory.partid` etc. fields.

Comment: I don't want the rows to be identical, they shouldn't be.

Comment: Then your "sample result" should look like how you *want* it to look, not what your current query returns. We already know that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A simplyfied example if you want to still get the part informations:

```
  SELECT orderid,
         partid,
         sum(Qty)
    FROM yourTable
GROUP BY oderid, partid
```

So, this groups the table by `oderid` and `partid` and returns the sum of `Qty` for each group. For more details on how to use `group by`, give Google a chance. Here is [one tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlgroupby.php) I found instantly.

Comment: When I add the GROUP BY to my code I get "Column 'Inventory.price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Yeah, that's what my comment on your question already stated. That's how `group by` works.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) statement with DISTINCT keyword instead of GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Col1,
       Col2,
       ...
FROM ...
```